# How to attach the position/rotation of a GameObject to the position/rotation Camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on the kinect V2, and i would like to make a script witch attaches the position of a game object ( moving with a head tracker) and the camera of my scene, to make an illusion of hologram.

I access it with the camera as a child of the game object, a lookat for a camera orbital ( rotation ), and a projection matrix for the camera to flip some axis of the camera.

But the projection matrix make some bugs with the textures and lighting of my scene. That´s why I would like to create a c# script who say:

Position camera = position gameobject (x,y,-z)

If position gameobject x>0 Else rotation camera y increase.

If position gameobject x<0 Else rotation camera y decrease.

If position gameobject y>0 Else rotation camera y decrease.

If position gameobject y<0 Else rotation camera y increase.

Nothing to do for the rotation camera z axis.

Can you help me to traduce this in C# ?

This is not my script :) but only the main idea i would like to do. I hope receive your help for a beginner developer!

Thank´s a lot

Comment: Someone making this script may work but you would need to make at least some minamum tweaks. If you plan to use Unity without any scripting knowledge I suggest looking into PlayMaker http://www.hutonggames.com/. You seem to have the logic and this will allow you to do what you want. It was used in Blizzards game Hearthstone so you know it can be powerful.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer! i'm looking this.
But my scene is ready, i began the script but i'm searching in Unity API wich script could attach the position between two objects, and how to do the conditions (example: If position gameobject x>0 Else rotation camera y increase.)
Can you give me just an example please?

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of hard to tell what you want. Here is some psuedo code that should help you on your way. I do not have unity to test it and it is not complete. But it will give you the basics to learn what you are trying to do.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScript: MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject camera;
    public GameObject gameObject;
    public int rotationAmount = 1;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        Vector3 camera = new Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, gameObject.transform.position.y, -gameObject.transform.position.x);

        if(gameObject.transform.position > 0) {
            camera.x -= rotationAmount;
        }

        camera.transform.position = camera;
    }
}
```

You will have to name the C# script TestScript drag it on a GameObject and drag your camera and gameObject into its slots. If you do not know how to do this I suggest you read into Unity more.

Comment: It´s perfect for me! I know read and create à basic script but i need to work it more. I know Unity3D so with your help it could be good. I'll give you feedbacks. Thank´s à lot!!

Comment: Hi!

I tried the script but it say that " Operator `>' cannot be applied to operands of type `UnityEngine.Vector3' and `int' "
My Game Object is a child, is this a problem?
Thank's for all!

Comment: I solved my problem but now it's written:
`HeadCamera.camera' hides inherited member `UnityEngine.Component.camera'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
`HeadCamera.gameObject' hides inherited member `UnityEngine.Component.gameObject'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

Comment: change if(gameObject.transform.position > 0) { to if(gameObject.transform.position.x > 0) {

Comment: I updated my script like that:
if(gameObject.transform.localPosition.x > 0) 
  {
   camera.y -= rotationAmount;
  }
I used a localPosition because the gameObject is a child of a prefab
But I still have a problem, my camera is not attached :(